# QString to char not working

Tags: c++, qt

I try the following where I added date and time but now nothing is written to the file. ??

```
QString hoho = QDate::currentDate().toString("yyyy.MM.dd") + QTime::currentTime().toString(".hh.mm.ss.zzz");
fprintf(fp, "%s timer timer3 timer5 timer6 timer7\n", hoho.toStdString().c_str());
```

Comment: Not sure why as I've never use QT with C before, but i did notice you have an extra period in your second time format "QTime::currentTime().toString(".hh.mm.ss.zzz");"  should be  QTime::currentTime().toString("hh.mm.ss.zzz");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FILE* is normally fully buffered, meaning nothing is written to the file until the internal buffer of the FILE* is full, or until you flush the FILE* (flushing is also done when closing the file).

So flush it by adding this after the fprintf() call:

```
fflush(fp);
```